# struggled with a problem with my email confirmation order notification system

Tags: email, migration, confirmation

I'm struggled with a problem with my email confirmation order notification system (which are not sent) while other emails (such as invoice mail) are correctly sent.

I haven't found any post with this problem, does anyone can help me?

Ps: I am currently migrating a plateform from OpenCart to Magento. (During this period both plateforms are running on the same server   and magento is running under a subdomain name). 
Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: Is there any error you see in the logs (Magento logs, Firebug, PHP-Error log,...)? Any 3rd party extensions which you use for checkout?

Answer (score 0):

- Check your logs.
- Try disabling any extensions related to email delivery. i.e. SendGrid
- Make sure they aren't stuck in the mail spool
- Check your spam filter